# How to write unstack and reindex in dask?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dask, reindex

I write the script in pandas but because of efficinecy i need to switch to dask but i am not sure how to implement `unstack` and `reindex` in dask?

This is how my pandas script looks:

```
df_new = df.groupby(['Cars', 'Date'])['Durations'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=list_days,index=list_cars,fill_value=0).\
    round().reset_index().fillna(0).round()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the result of a `.groupby()` aggregation will be small and fit in memory. As show in https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-best-practices.html#reduce-and-then-use-pandas, you can use Dask for the large aggregation, and then pandas for the small in-memory post-processing.

```
df_new = (
    df.groupby(['Cars', 'Date'])['Durations'].mean()
      .compute()  # turn the Dask DataFrame into a pandas dataframe
      .unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=list_days,index=list_cars,fill_value=0).
      .round().reset_index().fillna(0).round()
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought the similar solution to convert first to pandas. How i would change that back into dask dataframe?